# Multiple rules in where condition

Tags: sas, macros

I have a data for at application id level. The dataset has a unique row for each application id and almost 400 column depicting which rule the customer got hit when they applied to the bank. For example the data would look something like this

| Appl_id | Rule_1234 | R_4567 | R_1004 | R_9006 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| F_1234 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| F_7890 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Like the data above I have close to 450 rules in the data with each rule in different column. I have to create a code in which I have to specifically deal with three rules.

1)I need to create a dataset in which I can tell sas to give the output where the customers has hit only Rule_1234 and none other.

2. I Also need to tell sas that the customer has hit only_1234 and R_4567 and none of the other 400+ rules which means ( only two of them are 1 and all other are 0)

how do i do this?

the code that I am trying is below but its creating a different dataset every time its hitting the new rule and this is something I do not want

```
%macro test(

rules);
data rules_1;
set rules;
where r_1234 =1 and &rules.=0;
run;

%mend;
%test(R_4567);
%test(R_1004);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just want to use the SUM() function to test how many "rules" are true. You can use the MIN() function to test if all of the rules of interest are TRUE. You can use COUNTW() to see how many rules you are testing.

But to use the flexibility of variable lists you will need to switch from a WHERE statement to a subsetting IF statement instead.

```
IF sum(of rule_1234 r_:)=countw("rule_1234 &rules",' ')
  and min(of rule_1234 &rules)
;
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tom this should work

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your `where` statement into an `if` statement to take advantage of the double-dash shortcut and sum them. If the sum of all variables you're interested in checking are 0, then you know they are all 0.

You need to know the start and end variable for this to work. If they'll never change then you can write them directly, otherwise you can dynamically retrieve them  using dictionary.columns.

```
/* Rule 1 */
data want;
    set rules;
    if(r_1234 = 1 AND sum(of r_4567--r_9006) = 0);
run;

/* Rule 2 */
data want;
    set rules;
    if(r_1234 = 1 AND r_4567 = 1 AND sum(of r_1004--r_9006) = 0);
run;
```

To dynamically get the start and end variables with dictionary.columns:

```
proc sql;
    select CASE when(varnum = min(varnum) ) then name END
         , CASE when(varnum = max(varnum) ) then name END
    into :start_var separated by ' '
       , :end_var separated by ' '
    from dictionary.columns
    where     memname = 'RULES'
          AND libname = 'WORK'
          AND upcase(name) NOT IN('APPL_ID', 'R_1234')
    ;
quit;
```

`&start_var` and `&end_var` can be used dynamically in the sum statement:

`sum(of &start_var.--&end_var.) = 0`

Comment: Thank you so much stu - this should work

Comment: Hi! This code is not giving me the correct results somehow strangely

Comment: If you can provide an example of data where it does not work then I can diagnose it and try to provide a solution.

Comment: I have modified the code like this (if r_1234=1 and sum(r_1234 —r_6789)=1

Comment: The above code is working fine but not working fine if I want to check two conditions together, and I can’t understand why?

Comment: `sum(r_1234--r_6789)` will only equal 1 if just one of the variables is equal to 1. Consider if `r_1234`, `r_3456`, and `r_6789` were all 1. The sum of them would be 3. You would need to modify it to be `if(r_1234 = 1 and r_3456 = 1 and r_6789 = 1)` or `sum(r_1234--6789) = 3`.

Comment: I get you , This worked for me now